# Can't find eigenvalues and eigenvectors, characteristic polynomial is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors given this linear map: $L: \Bbb Z_7^3[x] →\Bbb  Z_7^3[x]$ $$L(p) = (4x+1)p' + p(1)(2-3x-x^2)-3p'(1)(1+x^2)+3p(-1)$$
I get a characteristic polynomial that is irreducible, so the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic polynomial. I can't get integer roots. How do I find eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

*$Z_7^3[x]$ is a vector space of all polynomials that have a degree less than 4. Also the coefficients are remainders of division by 7 (Have to be from this set: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.*

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What  do you denote $\Bbb Z_7^3[x]$, exactly?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks Bernard. $Z_7^3[x]$ is a vector space of all polynomials that have a degree less than 4. Also the coefficients are remainders of division by 7 (Have to be from this set: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.